# How to implement useInput hook with refs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a generic `useInput` hook that comes with a ref to the input DOM. I'd use the ref from `useInput` inside `Form` component to grab all the input values when the form is submitted.

I'm having trouble understanding how to implement `useRef` to grab the value whenever the input DOM's value changes. So far all it does is keep logging `undefined` for the ref...

What I tried:

```js
  const useInput = ({ label, name }, ref) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const inputRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
      const { current } = inputRef;
      console.log(current); // logs undefined - shouldn't it refer to the input dom?
    }, [value])

    const input = (
      <Form label={label}>
        <input name={name} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} ref={inputRef}/>
      </Form>
    )

    return [value, input];
  };

  export default useInput;
```

Comment: did you try logging `inputRef` itself?

Comment: You should consider using React.forwardRef because it is officially for your use-case. It helps forwarding ref to HTML elements easily.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work - I forgot to update `inputRef.current` inside `useEffect` as the value state changes -  Not sure if this is best practice though...

```js
  const useInput = ({ label, name }, ref) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const inputRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
      inputRef.current = value // *added this line, so it updates the ref as state changes.
    }, [value])

    const input = (
      <Form label={label}>
        <input name={name} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} ref={inputRef}/>
      </Form>
    )

    return [value, input, inputRef]; // also added inputRef as an output so I can consume it
  };

  export default useInput;
```